# values are not aligned properly under single column

Tags: html, css

In below image, you can see all values inside table are aligned in single line properly except under  sku column.

[image]

we are using following code :

```
<td class ="skuam">
<?php echo $sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($products->getId())->getSku();?>
</td>
```

I tried increasing `top : 10px;` but its working only for one row.

```
    .wk_row_view td {
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .wk_first_td {
        width: 26%;
        border-left: none!important;
    }

    .skuam {
    Position:relative;
    top:0px;
    }
```

```css
    .wk_row_view td {
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    
    .wk_first_td {
        width: 26%;
        border-left: none!important;
    }
    
    .skuam {
    Position:relative;
    top:0px;
    }
```

```html
<table>User9999: Please fill this</table>
```

Comment: Why the relative and 0px then? Show the generated HTML instead of the PHP

Comment: we are using php code for getting values of "sku"

Comment: But that has nothing to do with the representation - that is the CSS and the markup

Comment: is it allowed post link of demo site & demo credentials here ?

Comment: Just post the table using the snippet editor

Comment: I see the `.ama1 { .... top:10px` is pushing all the inputs down too - please delete your credential comment

Comment: Your question is actually off topic since it has no value to other users without the reproducible code IN the question. Can you add your table with enough CSS to show the problems?

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for your support. i got solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `vertical-align: middle;` in all `td` tags.

```
.wk_row_view td {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```